# Jest cannot find core-js module

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, core-js

I get an intermittent error with jest -

`Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es.symbol.description' from 'vue.runtime.common.dev.js'`

I seem to get this when trying to access `global` within jest. I also got this when trying to use a fetch mock library.

After checking core-js library, I cannot find a file with that name.

I have no idea how to sort this.

We are using core-js 2.6.9